# Find result with hasmany relationship in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, relational-database

I am just starts a project in laravel and this is new environment for me. I am familiar with PHP and also models relationship. But the laravel structure is little bit complex for starting.
So the problem is I have a question and Course table, A single question may have more then one course so i created one more table which hold course id and question id.

Question Model

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Question extends Model{

    protected $primaryKey = "id";

    public function courses(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\CourseQuestion');
    }
}
```

Course model

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Course extends Model {
    protected $primaryKey = "id";

    public function questions(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\CourseQuestion');
    }
}
```

And last courseQuestion model

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CourseQuestion extends Model {
    protected $primaryKey = "id";

    public function questions(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Question');
    }

    public function courses(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Course');
    }
}
```

And my controller where i getting result -

```
class IndexController extends BaseController {

    public function index(){
        $user = Question::with('user','courses','branches')->find(100);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($user); die;
    }
}
```

So the courses return only id of course and questions which store in third table but i want the course name respective id. Please help
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Question extends Model
{

    protected $primaryKey = "id";

    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\CourseQuestion', 'course_question_id', 'id')
         ->select('id', 'name');
    }
}
```

Comment: >Like wise change all function...  
>hasmany/hasone/belongsto   
>1=> models path  
>2=> local_foreignkey name  
>3=> primarykey of master table  
>and finaly use select to get some additional specific fields if you require  
>without select you can get whole data.

Comment: This answer is satisfied to you..?